# Mapping / to root in Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, webserver

I'm trying to map my servlet  to server everything off of the root URL. It looks as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My war file is register.war. When I run this in tomcat, I'm having to use www.myurl.com/register/. What I want to use however, is www.myurl.com/

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this without renaming my register.war to root.war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to your Tomcat configuration and change the context path for that particular web application. You will find it in

```
/tomcat_installation/conf/context.xml
```

[The various elements are detailed here.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) You're looking for `docBase` and `path` attributes.